# Submit não chama função

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

Depois de alterar o código, deixei desta forma mas analisei o console do navegador e percebi que o botão de submit continua não chamando a função:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="spacer">
<div class="row contact">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">

<form id="form-ajax">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo:" id="nome">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail:" id="email">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número para contato:" id="num">
        <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" id="msg"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#form-ajax').click(function(e){  
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('entrou na função');
    if($('#enviar').val() === 'Enviando...'){
    return(false);
    }

    $('#enviar').val('Enviando...');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpmailer.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'nome':$('#nome').val(),
            'email':$('#email').val(),
            'num':$('#num').val(),
            'msg':$('#msg').val()
            }
    }).done(function(data){

        alert(data);
        $('#nome').val();
        $('#email').val();
        $('#num').val();
        $('#msg').val();

    });
});
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Já experimentaste chamar a função no botão?

Answer (score 3):

passe o script do jquery para o head se ainda não o tiver.

depois coloque o

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...o seu script atual aqui   
});
```

e por fim passe o e.preventDefault(); logo para baixo do

```
$('#form-ajax').submit(function(e) {
     e.preventDefault();
```

Comment: Ja fiz, o estranho é quando aperto no botão submit ele retorna pra pagina limpando os campos, mas sem entrar no script

Comment: Então troca o submit por um button. e chama em vez de submit() o click()

Comment: Editei o post veja como ficou o código. Agora quando clico no botão do formulário não acontece nada.

Comment: esta quase ;) agora troque o form_ajax por enviar   $('#enviar').click(function(e){

Comment: alterei e novamente não aconteceu nada quando clico no botão

Comment: Ponha o codigo todo da página num gist e envie-me o link

Comment: https://gist.github.com/ricardofeller/d18c54ba47d16d013e56ea5b466e1035

Comment: Primeiro falta lhe um igual no id do fórum. 2 você co segue ver o alerta?

Comment: não consigo ver o alerta, corrigi o igual que estava faltando

Answer (score 1):

O Problema é que o script jQuery é executado antes da página ser totalmente carregada então ele não consegue atribuir o evento ao form pois este não existe ainda. Você pode resolver isso de 2 formas:

1 - Você trazer o script pro fim da página.

2 - Colocar todo script dentro da função "ready" do jQuery para dizer que o script só deve ser executado depois da página ser carregada, assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //...o seu script atual aqui
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Insira seu script dentro da função abaixo.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    // Aqui
});
```

Isso vai fazer com que seu script seja executado somente após o carregamento da página.
Um dica: sempre coloque seus scripts após o conteúdo das páginas, antes de fechar a tag body para evitar que os mesmos não bloqueem o carregamento da página por possíveis erros no script.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $('#form-ajax').submit(function(e){
           alert('entrou na função');
    if($('#enviar').val() === 'Enviando...'){
           return(false);
    }$('#enviar').val('Enviando...');

    $.ajax({
        url: 'phpmailer.php',
        type: 'post',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            'nome':$('#nome').val(),
            'email':$('#email').val(),
            'num':$('#num').val(),
            'msg':$('#msg').val()
            }
    }).done(function(data){

        alert(data);
        $('#nome').val();
        $('#email').val();
        $('#num').val();
        $('#msg').val();

    });
    e.preventDefault();
     });
 });
</script>
```

Veja se assim funciona, não esqueça da biblioteca JQuery, antes do script.