# PHPMailer sem ajax

Tags: php, html, phpmailer

Tenho um form que estou passando via post para o script do phpmailer, após enviar ele redireciona para outra pagina dizendo se o form foi enviado ou não, mas não retorna a pagina do form, tentei fazer via ajax e não consegui:

> [Submit não chama função](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135146/submit-n%C3%A3o-chama-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o/135199?noredirect=1#comment280131_135199)

teria algum modo de enviar o form por php e retornar a pagina somente com o php?

Meu form:

```
<div class="row contact">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">

<form id="form" method="post" action="mail/phpmailer.php">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo:" name="nome">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail:" name="email">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número para contato:" name="num">
        <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" name="msg"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

Configuração do PHPMailer:

```
<?php
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer();
$mail->setLanguage('pt');

$from = '-@-.com.br';
$fromName = '-';

$host ='smtp.umbler.com';
$username ='-@-.com.br';
$password ='-';
$port =587;
$secure =false;

$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = $host;
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = $username;
$mail->Password = $password;
$mail->Port = $port;
$mail->SMTPSecure = $secure;

$mail->From = $from;
$mail->FromName = $fromName;
$mail->addReplyTo($from, $fromName);

$mail->addAddress('-@-.com', '-');

$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'utf-8';
$mail->WordWrap = 70;                            

$mail->Subject = 'Contato ';
$mail->Body    = 'Nome: ' .$_POST['nome'] . 'Email: ' . $_POST['email'] . 'Numero: ' . $_POST['num'];
$mail->AltBody    = $_POST['msg'];

$send = $mail->Send();

if($send)
    echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';
else
    echo 'Erro : '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
?>
```

Desta forma após apertar no enviar ele vai para a pagina do phpmailer.php e informa se foi enviado ou não, mas não retorna para a pagina do formulário...

Comment: Como tem a configuração do envio do email? Quer que ele redirecione para alguma página consoante o email ser enviado ou não?

Comment: Editei a pergunta, veja como esta meu codigo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se o seu form estiver em uma página PHP isso é simples. Da pra fazer com jQuery, mas pelo que entendi, você quer uma solução simples.

```html
<?php 

   if (isset($_GET['sucesso'])) {
  
   if ($_GET['sucesso']==1) {   ?>

        <div class="sucesso">Formulário enviado com sucesso!</div>

   <?php } else { ?>

        <div class="semsucesso">Erro enviando formulário</div>

    <?php 
    } 
}
?>


<div class="row contact">
<div class="col-lg-6 col-sm-6 ">

<form id="form" method="post" action="mail/phpmailer.php">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Nome completo:" name="nome">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail:" name="email">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Número para contato:" name="num">
        <textarea rows="6" class="form-control" placeholder="Digite sua mensagem" name="msg"></textarea>
        <input type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="enviar" value="Enviar">
</form>
</div>
</div>
```

E no PHP que envia o email altere no final:

```html
if($send)
    header("Location: pagina-do-form.php?sucesso=1\n\n");    
else
    header("Location: pagina-do-form.php?sucesso=0\n\n");
```

Assim ele retorna a pagina do form (em PHP) e exibe uma DIV com o resultado (sucesso ou nao).

Comment: Eu tentei por ajax e quebrei demais a cabeça por não ter muito conhecimento sobre... tenho até outra pergunta tentando via ajax: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/135146/submit-n%C3%A3o-chama-fun%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: Vou tentar com a sua dica

Comment: Fiz as alterações mas na pagina do form gerou um Notice: Undefined index: sucesso.

Comment: Alterei um pouco o código. Perdão, os erros "Notice" ficam desabilitados no meu servidor, então não vi :-) Tenta agora com o código atualizado. O isset() vai previnir contra esse erro.

Comment: dei uma ultima melhorada, agora deve funcionar 100%.

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado!

Answer (score 3):

Adicione isso ao fim de seu PHP, alterando apenas a URL.

```
if($send){
  echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';
  echo '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="3;URL="paginadoformulario.HTML">';
}
else{
    echo 'Erro : '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Veja se resolve seu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Pode usar o próprio form

```
<form id="form-ajax" method="POST" action="sua pagina aqui">
```

Existe um bom tutoral sobre forms no [w3school](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp)

Answer (score -2):

```
if($send){
    echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!';
    sleep(1);
    echo '<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>';
} else {
    echo 'Erro : '.$mail->ErrorInfo;
}
```

Comment: Coloque isso no fim do seu codigo

Comment: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'else'

Comment: desculpa, coloca assim:

} else {

Comment: Na realidade basta você acrescentar o 
sleep(1); e o
echo '<script>window.history.go(-1)</script>';
no seu código

Comment: O código ta errado, você esqueceu de colocar { depois do ' if ($send) '.

Comment: funcionou, obrigado, sabe se tem como eu gerar um alerta pra informar o usuário se foi enviado ou não?

Comment: Coloquei as chaves onde faltavam e funcionou :)

Comment: beleza , o importante é fazer funcionar e entender :)

Comment: ao invés de echo 'E-mail enviado com sucesso!'; coloca:
echo "<script>alert('E-mail enviado com sucesso!');</script>";